# Print file from WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf, printing, wcf-data-services, system.printing

I have a WCF Service Operation that receives an image as a Byte stream, and should print that image locally on the server **silently**. No dialogs or popups, when the service is called it should send the image to the printer straight away.

I am trying with a local image stored on the server using `PrintDocument.Print()`.

The weird thing is that it works on Visual Studio's integrated development server, but not on IIS 7.5. I have given the app pool admin rights (I'm actually using the identity of the logged on user, which is an admin) but no luck.

From both Visual Studio's server and from IIS I can see the available printers, but when I call the service from IIS nothing happens, and I mean *nothing*. No error, no exception, no sign of what's going on at all.

I have tried using `ProcessStartInfo` with `Verb = "print"` and `Verb = "PrintTo"` but the same thing happens. Works on Visual Studio but not on IIS.

I have also tried creating a `PrintTicket` and a `LocalPrintServer` with `PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter` rights but I don't know what to actually do with it, I don't know how to tell it to print an image file.

I know printing can be a tricky task on any language/platform, but is it really **that** hard to print an image from a WCF Data Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Wanna bang my head against the wall now. It was obviously a permissions issue, so
setting the Owner of the printer to the **Admin** users group (it was set to **System**) did the trick.

I'm really missing Linux right now :P

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you did? I am having the same issue and I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: how are you printing? it was a number of different things but maybe i can give you a hand